# O(log(n)) vs. O(log(n)^p)

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

I just wanted to double check my intuition. I suspect a polylog dominates a log, so `log(n)` is `O(log(n)^p)`. I read somewhere that powers of logs sometimes get thrown away like constants, so I wanted to double check.

Comment: What do you mean by `O(log(n))` is `O(log(n)^p)`? Big-O notation represents a set of functions. A function of f(_n_) is _in_ Big-O expression O(_e_) if there exists a positive factor _c_ and minimum _n0_ such that f(_n_) <= _c_*_e_ for all _n_ >= _n0_.  Are you asking whether these two Big-O expressions are equivalent? No they're not, because there are functions of _n_ in the second that are not in the first.

Comment: Sorry I realized what I said didn't make any sense and also it is clear that log(n) is O(log(n)^p). I guess my real question is whether log(n)^p is O(log(n)). I'm pretty sure it isn't but I haven't proved it yet.

Comment: No it isn't. Subtract 1 from the exponent on both sides. Is log(n)^(p-1) _in_ O(1)? Not if _p_ > 1.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, `log(x^a) = a*log(x)`, so in that case this will just be a factor. In your case you cannot simplify the power since it is outside of the log. I think your intuition may be good.

EDIT: Furthermore, `log(n)/log(n)^p = 1/log(n)^(p-1)` and for `p > 1`, the limit of this expression is `0`. This explains your intuition (along with some basic notions on asymptotic comparison).

Comment: There's something not quite correct about your grouping of these expressions.